# How to selectively sleep hard drives in Windows 10

Tags: hard-drive, windows-10

I have a 1TB 850 EVO for my primary storage and a 2TB WD RE4 for cold storage. The WD hardly ever gets used, however for obvious reasons I never want my SSD to sleep. Is there a solution to configure only my hard drive to sleep after inactivity?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[This link](http://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/21454-hard-disk-turn-off-after-idle-windows-10-a.html) should provide you with a detailed guide on how to do the settings. You basically need to go to Advance Power Plan Settings and manage the Hard Disk time until turning off settings and set it to the desired value. This setting shouldn't affect any SSDs on your system.

Post back if you have other questions! :)

Captain_WD.

Comment: So, basically, he has to do nothing? Because, the default of that value is 30 min, isn't it?

Comment: All drives go to a standby/sleep mode after certain amount of no usage. OP can set that time lower if they'd like to have their drives spin down sooner than 30 minutes of no usage. :)

Comment: So one can't _selectively sleep hard drives_ ?

Comment: @Captain_WD the vast majority of drives have the ability to standby after a period of inactivity, but they must be told to do so.  The question is how do you get Windows to tell one drive to do so but not another.  The windows setting applies to all drives.

Comment: @psusi We can simply set a low value for the idle-to-sleep timer in power settings which will affect all disks. then write a script to "ping" each disk via a read operation at some interval on a per disk basis. This will keep the disk awake. Each drive can then have it's own wake/sleep cycle with the base line being the min value.

Answer (score 10):

**Turn Off Sleep Function Of HDD**

1. Install "CrystalDiskInfo"

https://crystalmark.info/en/download/

2. Choose:
   "Function" ->
   "Advanced Feature" ->
   "AAM/APM Control"
3. Select your disk 
   and set the bottom slider 
   [below "Advanced Power Management (APM)"] 
   maximally on right side.

Choose - "Enable"

4. Choose:
   "Advanced Feature" ->
   and select "Auto AAM/APM Adaption"
5. Choose:
   "Function" 
   and select "Startup" and "Resident"

Ready

Comment: Thanks. For reference, "Auto AAM/APM Adaption" sets the AAM/APM every time CrystalDiskInfo runs,  "Resident" places CrystalDiskInfo in the system tray, and "Startup" starts CrystalDiskInfo at Windows boot.

Comment: For everyone else wondering as I did - yes, set the slider all the way to the right towards Performance, not Min Power. It will spin down the drive.